# Zeros of a function of degree 4

Tags: functions, roots

I'm trying to show that the following function has no zeros
$$
60x^4-44x^3-25x^2-44x+60=0.
$$
I already tried using Eisenstein's criterium, but since the first and the last coefficient are both $60$, there is no prime which holds.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question

Comment: The roots are $(11\pm  A(2\sqrt{574}+iB\sqrt{1183-A\sqrt{574}}))/60$, with $A,B=\pm 1$, none of which is real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/376294/5531) I showed that the polynomial

$$
p(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + ax + 1
$$

has no real zeros if $|a| \leq 4$ and $b > 2 |a| -  2$.

We have

$$
60x^4-44x^3-25x^2-44x+60 = 60 \left(x^4 - \frac{44}{60}x^3 - \frac{25}{60}x^2 - \frac{44}{60}x+1\right),
$$

so in this case $a = -44/60$ and $b = -25/60$.  Indeed, $|a| \leq 4$ and

$$
b = -\frac{25}{60} > -\frac{32}{60} = 2|a|-2,
$$

so the given polynomial has no real zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Following the hint in the comments, we divide by $x^2$ and rearrange to get $$60\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-44\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)-25=0$$
Set $y=x+\frac{1}{x}$ and note that $y^2=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2$ to get
$$60(y^2-2)-44y-25=0$$
which rearranges to the quadratic $$60y^2-44y-145=0$$
This has roots $y\approx -1.23, 1.96$.  [Alternate answer: $g(y)=60y^2-44y-145$ is an upward-pointing parabola, and $g(2)>0$ and $g(-2)>0$, so any roots are in $(-2,2)$.]

However $|x+\frac{1}{x}|\ge 2$ for all real $x$, so there are no real solutions.

Cute proof of the last fact: for $x>0$, the [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) gives $x+\frac{1}{x}\ge 2\sqrt{x\cdot \frac{1}{x}}=2$.